# Firebase- fetchProvidersForEmail - async error validation - email form validation

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

Having a bit of a hard time wrapping my head around trying to put the method below in the synchronous block of the form group. I know `fetchProvidersForEmail` is asynchronous, but couldn't I turn the method into a synchronous method.

When my custom validation method is put on the synchronous block a very strange error object is returned.

Is there no way I could use this method in the synchronous block of the form group? Is there a better way I could be doing this. Just trying to check if the email exists during the registration process.

> "@angular": "5.0.1", "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.5-next",
>   "firebase": "^4.12.0"

```js
//synchronous - returns strange error -- picture below
form = this.fb.group({
  email: [this.user.email, [
    Validators.email,
    Validators.required,
    CustomValidators.userEmailExists(this.afa)
  ]],
});

//asynchronous - returns fine
form = this.fb.group({
  email: [this.user.email, [
      Validators.email,
      Validators.required
    ],
    [
      CustomValidators.userEmailExists(this.afa)
    ]
  ],
});
```

```
//CustomValidatorService
```

```js
static userEmailExists(afa: AngularFireAuth) {
  return (control: AbstractControl) => {
    const email = control.value.toLowerCase();
    if (this.EMAIL_REGEXP.test(email)) {
      return firebase.auth()
        .fetchProvidersForEmail(email)
        .then(arr => arr.length ? {
          userEmailExists: true
        } : null);
    }
    return Observable.of(null);
  };
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the validator code?

Comment: Hi @TomaszKula, its up now. Good catch, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is your async validator will always return null, because Observable.of(null) returns synchronously, and your promise never has the change to return.

Also it looks like you are trying to access `this` inside a static method, which definitely won't work. I'm talking about `this.EMAIL_REGEXP`. You should define the regexp in the method itself.

I would not mix observables and promises in one validator. So given that fetchProvidersForEmail() returns a promise, lets just stick to promises:

```
static userEmailExists(afa: AngularFireAuth) {
  return (control: AbstractControl) => {
   const EMAIL_REGEXP = /my-awesome-regexp/;
   const email = control.value.toLowerCase();
    return EMAIL_REGEXP.test(email) ?
      Promise.resolve(null) :
      firebase.auth()
        .fetchProvidersForEmail(email)
        .then(arr => arr.length ? {
          userEmailExists: true
      } : null);
  };
}
```